# Fetch Google Checkout order id in App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-checkout

I have Jave App Engine app.

I would like to fetch to see if an order number exists in google checkout from it. Is this possible?

All I need to do is just check if an order number exists in my account. It would also be nice to fetch basic info as well, but not essential.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is possible.

Hi, if you are using the Java App Engine, you should take a look Google Checkout API for Java.
Whatever supported by the API should be available from Java as well.

- [Google Checkout API Blog](http://google-checkout-api.blogspot.com/)
- One way will be using the [Google Checkout API Order Report](http://bit.ly/gqCkAW)

Comment: Yes, but that API doesn't support app engine. I've manged to manually fetch the data via the raw XML service.

Comment: I've used the Checkout Java SDK on App Engine successfully. The release notes still say it is not supported but it works fine: